# Sort by date and time in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Can someone tell me how I can sort an array of items according to date and time. Currently, I am using

```
image.find({reviewed:true }, null, {sort:{"submittedDate":-1}}, 
           function (err, images) {})
```

My schema for date is:

```
submittedDate: Thu, 08 Nov 2012 15:42:47 GMT
```

But it sort only date wise. I want to sort first by time then by date.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not sort by _id. The first four bytes of the Object id is a timestamp, so should serve your purpose.

Comment: @almypal The _id (objectID) is meant to be unique, not sequential. Whilst most of the time it is, it can't be relied on

Comment: If generated by mongodb, it is unique and is a 12-byte value consisting of a 4-byte timestamp. They even recommend that you can extract insertion times from _id rather than having a separate timestamp field. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs and http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs

Comment: basically, I want to have the track of recent reviewed images so _id is not suitable here. Any other help?

Comment: @AliHassan - see my answer below

Comment: @alaxjamesbrown thanks for your reply but your sentax is not supported in my case it throws exception that .sort should be an object or string.

Comment: may be due to difference in version of mongoose.

Comment: I am using Mongoose v3.8 and have the same experience. Sorting by date/time seemed to be working with smaller data sets, but seems to be broken when I test it against larger data sets.

Answer (score 18):

The way to sort would be:

```
image.find({reviewed:true})
     .sort({'submittedDate': 'desc'})
     .exec(function(err, images) {
         //do stuff with images
     });
```

[Some documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort).

From v3.8.1, the syntax would be:

```
image.find({reviewed:true})
     .sort('submittedDate', -1)
     .execFind(function(err, images) {

 });
```

Comment: @VivekGhanchi not sure what you mean? it depends how you are storing your date time?

Comment: it works for me thanks its was issue from my model not from these query . +1

Comment: i find this just sorts alphanumericaly.

Answer (score 7):

As per version 5.11.13.

1. Add `{ timestamps: true }` in your Schema.

   `new Schema({}, { timestamps: true });`
2. Then Add "sort" to your query.

   `Model.find({}).sort({ createdAt: 'desc'}).exec();`

   `Model.find({}).sort({ createdAt: 'asc'}).exec();`

Thanks.